# I can't return parsing information in React Native

Tags: json, react-native, parsing, weather-api

i am a beginner programmist, i have decided to make my first project - weather app. though i have a problem , i cannot bring the parsed info out on screen but if i use console.log the info is shown in console.

i'm doing all these on site: https://snack.expo.io/

```
                   Copying you the codes and comment inside it console.logs


        **CODE**

 import React, { Component, createElement } from 'react';
    import {
      StyleSheet,
      Text,
      View,
      Image,
      ImageBackground,
      ActivityIndicator,
    } from 'react-native';

    class App extends Component {
      constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
          todos: [],
          isLoading: true,
        };
      }

      componentDidMount = async () => {
        fetch(
          'API'
        )
          .then(res => res.json())
          .then(data => {
            this.setState({ todos: data });

          })
          .catch(error => console.error(error))
          .finally(() => {
            this.setState({ isLoading: false });
          });
      };

      render() {
        const { data, isLoading } = this.state;
        return (
          <View>
          <Text>
          {data.sys.id}
          </Text>
          </View>
        );
      }
    }

    export default App;
```

Thank you !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had worked on your code by creating a weather api which is similar to your api and made some changes to the code its working now, check with this code.

This is the weather array iam getting from API, iam also using the weather API as yours

```
 Object {
    "description": "light intensity drizzle",
    "icon": "09d",
    "id": 300,
    "main": "Drizzle",
  },
```

**code:**

```
import React, { Component, createElement } from 'react';
        import {
          StyleSheet,
          Text,
          View,
          Image,
          ImageBackground,
          ActivityIndicator,
        } from 'react-native';

        class App extends Component {
          constructor(props) {
            super(props);
            this.state = {
              todos: [],
              isLoading: true,
            };
          }

          componentDidMount = async () => {
            fetch(
              'https://samples.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=London&appid=439d4b804bc8187953eb36d2a8c26a02'
            )
              .then(res => res.json())
              .then(data => {
                this.setState({ todos: data });
              })
              .catch(error => console.error(error))
              .finally(() => {
                this.setState({ isLoading: false });
              });
          };

          render() {
            return (
                <View style={{flex:1,justifyContent:"center",alignItems:"center"}}>
                    <Text>Hello</Text>
                    <Text>
                        {this.state.todos.weather != undefined ? this.state.todos.weather[0].description : null}
                    </Text>
                    <Text>
                        {this.state.todos.weather != undefined ? this.state.todos.weather[0].main : null}
                    </Text>
                </View>
            );
          }
    }

    export default App;
```

[image]

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. But, when im changing all this , im have the same error : - undefined is not an object (evaluating 'this.state.todos.weather[0]') =(  @<user12129132>

Comment: Made some changes to my code can you please check what's you are getting in console by printing todos after setState

Comment: Thank you and sorry for disturbing you. I tried a lot of different changes, i tried your version too , but each time the problem is same - "undefined is not an object". Also , when i write console.log(this.state.todos) after setState, it writes all arrays and objects @<user12129132>..

Comment: The reason why this error showing is render function is calling before fetching api what you can do is change the render function to <Text>{this.state.todos !== [] ? this.state.todos[0].description : null} check this I think it will work, made changes to my answer check that once.

Comment: Thank you for your patience. It still doesn't work. when i use to return <Text>{this.state.todos}</Text> and use this.setState({todos:data.weather}) i have error: "Objects are not valid as a React child (found: object with keys {id, main, description, icon})" . but, when i change the setState to this.setState({todos:data}) and try to return i have this error-  "Objects are not valid as a React child (found: object with keys {coord, weather, base, main, visibility, wind, clouds, dt, sys, timezone, id, name, cod})".  @<user12129132>

Comment: @LevanAmashukeli made some changes to my answer I had worked on changing your code and used a API as yours, I had checked the code it's working perfectly. Kindly check this code and check whether your api is giving proper response with console logs. Hope this helps!

Comment: Thank you very very very much for your patience and  your kindly help. Im new user here and dont know, if i can put like or subscribe or to write a good review for you. Kindly regard!

Comment: Thank you for that , iam glad that I helped you.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly you are using the wrong object name.

This is wrong.

```
const { data, isLoading } = this.state;
```

This is right.

```
const { todos, isLoading } = this.state;
```

Secondly
This is because you are trying to access the object which is not defined.

The app will load and render the page. And then the Api request is made.
So the data is not present. You can either set a default value or add a check.

```
render() {
    const { todos, isLoading } = this.state;
      return (
        <View>
          <Text>
           {todos.weather > 0 && todos.weather[0].description}
          </Text>
        </View>
      );
   }
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. But, it still doesn't work :( I tryed lot of wariants , but without any result( I have two versions of errors: 1) Object not defined  or 2) Objects are not valid as a React child (found: object with keys {id, main, description, icon}) @<user:13261398> @<Dipansh Khandelwal>